# Find K numbers whose product is N , keeping the maximum of K numbers to be minimum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sequence, product

Basically, we are given a number N and K, we need to find an array of size K such that the product of the array elements is N with the maximum of the elements being minimized.

for eg:

420 3

ans: 6 7 10
explanation: 420 can be written as the product of 6,10 and 7. Also it can be written as 5 7 12 but 10(maximum of 6 10 and 7) is minimum than 12(maximum of 5 7 12).

Constraints: numbers>0; 0 <= N < 10^6; 1<=k<=100

What I did so far was to first find the prime factors but after that I can't think of an efficient way to get the sequence.

Comment: Build a sorted list of all prime factors, while list size is > K  remove the smallest two numbers multiply and put the new number back in.  you can use minheaps too.

Comment: Already tried that, won't work. let's take the sample test itself: 420 can be written as 2 2 3 5 7 , mul 2 2 put back- 3 4 5 7 , mul 3 4 put back 5 7 12, which is wrong

Comment: For 420 a better solution would be `(-14)*(-30)*1` (or simply `(-420)*(-1)*1`), the maximum would be `1`

Comment: thank you for point out @chtz , I forgot to put the constraints.

Comment: what about array size for example for 1000 as a product what is the size you want to take. any constraint for this

Comment: @HarshGiri was adding that too

Comment: can the element of array be same, like 10*10*10 or 2* 6*6*10

Comment: @HarshGiri Yes.

Comment: so as per your question what should be the output of 1000, 3 and 720, 4

Comment: I should have used a pen and paper ! :)

Comment: the output be like 10*10*10 and 2*6*6*10, is it correct right

Comment: @HarshGiri for 1000,3 Yes. for 720,4 No. for 720 it would be 4 4 9 5

Comment: (Assuming you're only after positive factors) Built a list of pairs `<p, i>`, where `p` is a prime factor, and `i` is the number of times `p` can be divided into `N`.   Let `s` be the sum of `i`s.  If `s < K`, there is no solution.    Otherwise, you have at least one option of multiplying any pair of primes together if their respective `i > 1` together to obtain composite factors.   That isn't complete, but should be enough to get you started.

Comment: @Peter If `s<K` you can add `K-s` factors of `1`. Otherwise, your suggestion seems to be to make a brute-force search, right?

Comment: @Peter "If s < K, there is no solution": note that factors of 1 are allowed. There is always a solution.

Comment: @Peter First of all what chtz and Henry is saying is correct and secondly, It's already pretty obvious that we have to multiply pairs of prime factors till number of elements become K. I need to know how to efficiently choose which pairs to multiply.

Comment: @chtz - the approach will find all sets of `K` numbers.   It's not using any smarts to eliminate particular sets, other than checking them, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Henry - I was ignoring factors of `1`, yeah.

Comment: @Behl actually, 720 would be 4 5 6 6 (found with the algorithm shown in my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, [amritanshu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372992/amritanshu) had a pretty good [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772231/find-k-numbers-whose-product-is-n-keeping-the-maximum-of-k-numbers-to-be-minim#comment88551977_50772231): You have a list of the prime factors and split this list into a list containing the K biggest factors and another containing the other prime factors:

```
[2, 2], [3, 5, 7]
```

Then you multiply the biggest element of the first list with the smallest element of the second list and overwrite the element of the second list with the result. Remove the biggest element of the first list. Repeat these steps until your first list is empty:

```
[2, 2], [3, 5, 7]
[2], [6, 5, 7]  // 5 is now the smallest element
[], [6, 10, 7]
```

here another example:

```
N = 2310 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11
K = 3

[2, 3], [5, 7, 11]
[2], [15, 7, 11]
[], [15, 14, 11]
```

however, this algorithm is still not the perfect one for some cases like `N = 2310`, `K = 2`:

```
[2, 3, 5], [7, 11]
[2, 3], [35, 11]
[2], [35, 33]
[], [35, 66]  // better: [], [42, 55]
```

So, I thought you actually want to split the factors such that the factors are as close as possible to the Kth root of N. So I come up with this algorithm:

- calculate R, the smallest integer bigger than or equal to the Kth root of N
- calculate the gcd of R and N
- if the gcd is equal to R, add R to the list, call your algorithm recursively with `N / R, K-1`, add the result to the list and return the list
- if the gcd is not equal to R, add it to R and go to step 2

here is a little bit of python code:

```
import math

def gcd(a, b):

    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def root(N, K):

    R = int(math.exp(math.log(N) / K))
    if R ** K < N:
        R += 1
    return R

def find_factors(N, K):

    if K == 1:
        return [N]
    R = root(N, K)
    while True:
        GCD = gcd(N, R)
        if GCD == R:
            return [R] + find_factors(N // R, K-1)
        R += GCD
```

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that this algorithm is still giving incorrect results in many cases. The correct way is incrementing `R` until it divides `N`:

```
def find_factors(N, K):
    if K == 1:
        return [N]
    R = root(N, K)
    while True:
        if N % R == 0:
            return [R] + find_factors(N // R, K-1)
        R += 1
```

This way you don't need `gcd`.

Comment: Your last solution fails, e.g., for `N=17^3*72`, `K=3`

Answer (score 0):

Overall, I guess you need to factorize `N` and then essentially make some brute-force approach trying to combine the prime factors into combined factors of roughly equal size. Generally, that should not be too bad, because factorizing is already the most expensive part in many cases.

---

**Original answer (wrong)** (see comment by @gus):

Without proof of correctness, assuming `N>0`, `K>0`, in pseudo code:

- Factorize `N` into prime factors, store into array `F`
- find smallest integer `m>=0` such that `length(F) <= 2^m*K`
- Fill `F` by `1`s to get size `2^m*K`.
- For `i=m down to 1`

  - sort `F`
  - for `j=1 to 2^(i-1)*K`

    - `F[j] = F[j] * F[2^i*K+1-j]` (multiply smallest with largest, and so on)
  - `F=F[1:2^(i-1)*K]` (delete upper half of `F`)
- `F` contains result.

---

Example `420 3`:

- `F={2,2,3,5,7}`
- `m=1`
- `F={1,2,2,3,5,7}`
- `F={7,10,6}`  DONE

Example `2310 2`:

- `F={2,3,5,7,11}`
- `m=2`
- `F={1,1,1,2,3,5,7,11}` (fill to `2^m*K` and sort)
- `F={11,7,5,6}` (reduce to half)
- `F={5,6,7,11}` (sort)
- `F={55, 42}`  DONE

Example `N=17^3*72`, `K=3`

- `F={2,2,2,3,3,17,17,17}`
- `m=2`
- `F={1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,17,17,17}`
- `F={17,17,17,3,6,4}`
- `F={3,4,6,17,17,17}`
- `F={3,4,6,17,17,17}`
- `F={51,68,102}`